# JGrapht SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph class addEdge return null pointer (with all nodes are not null)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jgrapht

When I implemented constructing a graph (graph-cut algorithm in Markov Random Field),I do not know why when the Source node and target node are not null, why `addEdge()` function does not work and returns a null in one operation. Moreover,for the graph is created according to the training data, I feel too confused why just the record occur the situation. 
The code:

```
stofEdge[i][j]=dd.addEdge(Snode,fields[i][j]);
//stofEdge is used to store the created edges. When i=573 and j=2, the edge is null.
```

Comment: Are you getting a NullPointerException, or just a null refererence back from addEdge?

Comment: NullPointerException for I will used the "edge" object as well as a null reference. Thanks.

Comment: `addEdge` will thrown an NPE when you try to add a null vertex.  Are you sure `fields[i][j]` has a value?

Comment: Thanks, Yes, I am sure the two vertex variables （Snode and fields[i][j]) are not null.@Ireeder